# can someone help me edit this essay about u.s. vs. china: college admissions

Tags: grammar, characters, simplified-characters, sentence-structure

美国和中国的大学入˛取最重要地部分之一是标准化考试。尽管标准化考试在美国非常重要，但在中国更多。美国有两个标准化的测试选项。你可以选择采取任何你喜欢的考试。这两个考试遵循不同的规则，并基于不同的主题。对于那些喜欢英语和阅读的人来说，S.A.T.更好。对于那些喜欢数学和科学的人，他们会更喜欢A.C.T.。一些大学是可选的测试，所以学生甚至可能不需要参加考试。这个测试的学习时间平均为一年。我的一个朋友在参加实际考试之前只参加了一次实践考试。

在中国，情况并非如此。中国有一个标准化考试，高考。 它塑造了学生的生计，并对学生的期望提出了非常高的标准。中国的学生已经准备为她的入学考试基本上她的整个生活。她相信提供的信息，通过教师在正常上课时间是不够充分，并说，如果家庭有财政手段，他们支付他们的学生的课程以外的学校。在中国，接受着名大学的学生是百分之一学生的一半。 被接受的顶级学校意味着他们将有地位和权力。在中国，接受着名大学的学生是百分之一学生的一半。 被接受的顶级学校意味着他们将有地位和权力。 做得不好的学生必须要么重复一学年，要么接受他们的低等地位的未来。

区别源于他们接受学生时的看法。在美国，当他们选择学生时，他们看成绩，考试成绩，散文，课外活动，志愿者工作和建议。大学招生想知道你是和会什么样的人。由于申请顶级学校的学生是最聪明的学生，他们希望看到学生是否适合社区。有时，久负盛名的大学将接受一个学生，可能没有很好的测试，但有其他人才或能力。

在这两个国家，财富在大学录取过程中发挥了作用。如果一个学生更富有，他们可以聘请私人导师。因此，他们在高考上得分更高。学生谁负担不起私人教师,或不住在城市,通常比分更糟高考。这两个大学的过程都是不公平的。在美国，如果学生真的很特别，那么标准化考试就无关紧要了。在中国，如果你对高考做得不好，没有其他办法。 那些无法支付的人不会做得好，因此不会得到一份好工作。在美国，许多人说，由于大学的关系，青少年和年轻人的压力太大。中国的大学数量比美国少。因此，高校更具竞争力。美国有更多的学院和多功能性

当学生上大学时，他们正在寻找他们是谁。然而，在中国，你必须作出更早的决定；这是非常可怕的。而，中国学生做出的决定更为长久。与今天的美国学生不同的是，中国学生不以未定的专业开始上大学。

这些都是一些在中国和美国大学录取的大差异，他们告诉了很多关于每个国家的文化。

Comment: What's the purpose of this essay? If merely for informally communicating with people then it's mostly understandable to Chinese speakers, but if for formal uses, there are really a LOT of minor mistakes that need cleaning up.

Comment: Please finish your homework by yourself

Answer (score 1):

Well there are many small mistakes in the essay.You need to improve your grammar mainly.

美国和中国的大学录取学生最重要的部分就是标准化考试。尽管标准化考试在美国非常重要，但在中国甚至占据着更重要的地位。美国有两个标准化的测试选项。你可以选择采取任何你喜欢的考试。这两个考试遵循不同的规则，并基于不同的主题。对于那些喜欢英语和阅读的人来说，S.A.T.更好。但对于那些喜欢数学和科学的人，他们可能会更喜欢A.C.T.。还有一些大学是可选的测试，所以学生可能甚至不需要参加考试。这个测试的平均学习时间为一年。我的一个朋友在参加实际考试之前只参加了一次实践考试。

在中国，情况并非如此。中国有一个标准化考试————高考。 它决定了学生的生计，并对学生提出了非常高的标准。中国的学生已经准备为他的入学考试付出几乎整个生活。她相信提供的信息，通过教师在正常上课时间是不够充分的，而且，如果家庭有财政手段，他们会支付他们的学校课程以外的课外班费用。在中国，接受名牌大学教育的学生是及其少的。 被名牌大学录取意味着他们将有更好的机会和未来的工资。做的不好的学生要么再回到高三重修一年，我们称之为复读，或者，他们只能接受前景不好的未来。

两国的区别源于他们录取学生时的看法。在美国，当他们选择学生时，他们看考试成绩，散文，课外活动，志愿者工作和他人建议。大学招生想知道你现在是和会成为什么样的人。由于申请顶级学校的学生是最聪明的学生，他们希望看到学生是否适合社区。有时，久负盛名的大学接受的一个学生，可能没有很好的测试成绩，但有其他才能或能力。

在这两个国家，财富在大学录取过程中发挥了较大作用。如果一个学生更富有，他们可以聘请好滴私人导师。因此，他们在高考上将会得分更高。如果学生负担不起私人教师的费用,或不住在城市,那么通常情况下他的高考成绩就不如城市的学生。这两个考取大学的过程都是不公平的。在美国，如果学生真的很特别，那么标准化考试就无关紧要了。在中国，如果你高考成绩不好，那便没有其他办法。 那些无法支付课外培训费用的人不会考得好，因此将来将得不到一份好工作。在美国，许多人说，由于考大学的关系，青少年和年轻人的压力太大。然而中国的大学数量比美国少，故高校更具竞争力。由于美国有更多学院和大学。所以上大学时，他们更多的是在寻找他们自己本身是谁。然而，在中国，你必须更早作出决定，这是非常可怕的。中国学生做出的决定将指向更长久的未来。与今天的美国学生不同的是，中国学生都要选择一个具体的专业来开始大学课程。

这些都是中国和美国大学录取的差异，他们彰显了这两个国家不同的文化。

其实我觉得你的中文在以下几个方面还需提高：
1.不能用英文的语序来直译成中文（当然这也是很多中国学生学习英文时会犯的错误，担任需高度注意）
2.一个词的用法一定要注意，其在什么时候能用，能用做哪些意思。毕竟，就像英文里的phrase，一个词的用法可能会有很多。常用的词一定要掌握全部用法，这样才能在写作中灵活运用。
3.中文中如果要连用形容词或副词，必须要注意他们的顺序。

还有最重要的一点，在修改你的文章的时候，我并没有针对你的观点进行修改。我最大程度上保留了你的观点。但我作为一名中国大学生，我想说，你对于中国高考和中国大学的现状还不够了解，不过这无可厚非，毕竟国家之间的文化差异和地理上的距离差异本身就具有延迟性。你了解到的中国可能是十年前的中国。但对于高考，很多农村出身的孩子确实也能考的非常棒，因为这是他们唯一的出路。你所提及的财政原因决定高考成绩的问题，大多数是出现在像北京这样的城市。请容许我再提最后一点，关于你所说的公平问题，当今的中国大学生，大多都认为对于中国教育现状，高考是最公平的办法，并且，每年教育部也都在改革，不断努力地让新高考适应新时代的新环境，新学生。

如果我的回答能够给你带来一些帮助，感激不尽。

Comment: My answer contains two main parts.the already edited essay and my several suggestions.the last three paragraphs are my suggestions.Hope can help you.